# finding point on a line which is equidistant from 2 other points

Tags: algorithm, geometry, line, plane

I know I probably should have asked this question in math.stackexchange but answers there are mostly "pen-paper" type. I need an efficient approach to implement and that is why I am asking here.

Q: Given 2 points A & B and a line L. Points and line are 3D. How to find a point on the given line L which is equidistant from the given points A & B?

The approach I followed is:

- finding plane, P, perpendicular to line AB and passing through the center of A & B.
- point of intersection of P and L would be the answer.

I am working on large data-set (a 3d image) and doing the above calculations involves large no. of multiplications and divisions (on total).

So is there a better way of doing it.

A working code would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doubt there is any better way to do it. This is Q & A website , not one which is supposed to provide you with a working code for your problem with zero contribution from your side.

Comment: @shujj : Dude either try to help or just ignore the post. No one asked you specifically. And as far as contribution is concerned I am an active contributor to open source and this question is related to one of these open projects only. So don't f**king commment without being aware of the exact information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR.** The solution is at the bottom.

Alright, so let's say these are our parameters:

> ***x<sub>0</sub>*** and ***x<sub>1</sub>***, that describe the line.
>
> ***a*** and ***b***, the two points.

Where

> ***x<sub>0</sub>** = [x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>, z<sub>0</sub>]*
>
> ***x<sub>1</sub>** = [x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>, z<sub>1</sub>]*
>
> ***a** = [x<sub>a</sub>, y<sub>a</sub>, z<sub>a</sub>]*
>
> ***b** = [x<sub>b</sub>, y<sub>b</sub>, z<sub>b</sub>]*
>
> ***δ** = [δ<sub>x</sub>, δ<sub>y</sub>, δ<sub>z</sub>] = (**x<sub>1</sub>** - **x<sub>0</sub>**)*

Then our description of the line can be seen as a parametric function:

> *l(λ) = **x<sub>0</sub>** + λ*(**x<sub>1</sub>** - **x<sub>0</sub>**)*

So we are trying to find a value for λ that satisfies the following equation:

> *(l(λ) - **a**)<sup>2</sup> = (l(λ) - **b**)<sup>2</sup>*

(Here I'm cheating with notation a bit, so ***x**<sup>2</sup> = **x**.**x***)

So expanding everything we get:

> *(λx<sub>1</sub> + (1 - λ)x<sub>0</sub> - x<sub>a</sub>)<sup>2</sup>* +
>
> *(λy<sub>1</sub> + (1 - λ)y<sub>0</sub> - y<sub>a</sub>)<sup>2</sup>* +
>
> *(λz<sub>1</sub> + (1 - λ)z<sub>0</sub> - z<sub>a</sub>)<sup>2</sup>* =
>
> *(λx<sub>1</sub> + (1 - λ)x<sub>0</sub> - x<sub>b</sub>)<sup>2</sup>* +
>
> *(λy<sub>1</sub> + (1 - λ)y<sub>0</sub> - y<sub>b</sub>)<sup>2</sup>* +
>
> *(λz<sub>1</sub> + (1 - λ)z<sub>0</sub> - z<sub>b</sub>)<sup>2</sup>*

Simplifying, we get:

> *(λδ<sub>x</sub> + x<sub>0</sub> - x<sub>a</sub>)<sup>2</sup> +*
>
> *(λδ<sub>y</sub> + y<sub>0</sub> - y<sub>a</sub>)<sup>2</sup> +*
>
> *(λδ<sub>z</sub> + z<sub>0</sub> - z<sub>a</sub>)<sup>2</sup> =*
>
> *(λδ<sub>x</sub> + x<sub>0</sub> - x<sub>b</sub>)<sup>2</sup> +*
>
> *(λδ<sub>y</sub> + y<sub>0</sub> - y<sub>b</sub>)<sup>2</sup> +*
>
> *(λδ<sub>z</sub> + z<sub>0</sub> - z<sub>b</sub>)<sup>2</sup>*

Expanding the brackets and cancelling, we get:

> *-2δ<sub>x</sub>x<sub>a</sub>λ + (x<sub>0</sub> - x<sub>a</sub>)<sup>2</sup> +*
>
> *-2δ<sub>y</sub>y<sub>a</sub>λ + (y<sub>0</sub> - y<sub>a</sub>)<sup>2</sup> +*
>
> *-2δ<sub>z</sub>z<sub>a</sub>λ + (z<sub>0</sub> - z<sub>a</sub>)<sup>2</sup> =*
>
> *-2δ<sub>x</sub>x<sub>b</sub>λ + (x<sub>0</sub> - x<sub>b</sub>)<sup>2</sup> +*
>
> *-2δ<sub>y</sub>y<sub>b</sub>λ + (y<sub>0</sub> - y<sub>b</sub>)<sup>2</sup> +*
>
> *-2δ<sub>z</sub>z<sub>b</sub>λ + (z<sub>0</sub> - z<sub>b</sub>)<sup>2</sup>*

Which we can simplify further into some nice neat vector operations:

> *2λ**δ**.(**x<sub>b</sub>** - **x<sub>a</sub>**) =*
> *(**x<sub>0</sub>** - **x<sub>b</sub>**)<sup>2</sup> -* 
> *(**x<sub>0</sub>** - **x<sub>a</sub>**)<sup>2</sup>*

Which is pretty simple to rearrange to get a linear equation in λ with one unique solution.

Comment: It should be noted that:
1) There are no solutions if the RHS is non-zero and LHS is zero
2) There are infinitely many solutions if the RHS is zero and LHS is zero
3) There is one solution at $\vec{x_0}$ if RHS is zero and LHS is non-zero

Comment: To add to B-Brock's comment, the cases arise as follows: (1) Line is degenerate (gradient vector is 0) and x_a != x_b. (2) xa = xb (3) Not actually a special case, but an artifact of describing the line in terms of x_0 and x_1.

Answer (score 2):

If line L is described by parametric vector equation

```
P=C+t*D
```

(where C is some base point, D is direction vector, t is parameter)
then point P is equidistant from the given points A & B, when vector from P to the middle of A-B segment is perpendicular to AB vector. So scalar product of these vectors is zero.

```
(B-A)*(C+t*D-(A+B)/2)=0
```

Let's

```
F=B-A
G=C-(A+B)/2
```

then (in coordinate form)

```
Fx*(Gx+t*Dx)+Fy*(Gy+t*Dy)+Fz*(Gz+t*Dz)=0
t*(Dx*Fx+Fy*Dy+Fz*Dz)=-(Fx*Gx+Fy*Gy+Fz*Gz)
t=-(Fx*Gx+Fy*Gy+Fz*Gz)/(Dx*Fx+Fy*Dy+Fz*Dz)
```

case of `(Dx*Fx+Fy*Dy+Fz*Dz)=0` corresponds to perpendicular lines AB and L. In this case there is no solution when nominator `(Fx*Gx+Fy*Gy+Fz*Gz)` is non-zero, and there is infinity of solutions, if nominator is zero (all the points on line are equidistant)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve a system of equations to get the answer. A line in 3D is something of the sort of:

```
x = x<sub>0</sub> + t * v<sub>x</sub>
y = y<sub>0</sub> + t * v<sub>y</sub>
z = z<sub>0</sub> + t * v<sub>z</sub>
```

Let's denote the point we are searching for `P`. Now we have:

(P<sub>x</sub> - A<sub>x</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (P<sub>y</sub> - A<sub>y</sub>)<sup>2</sup> +(P<sub>z</sub> - A<sub>z</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = (P<sub>x</sub> - B<sub>x</sub>)<sup>2</sup> +
(P<sub>y</sub> - B<sub>y</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (P<sub>z</sub> - B<sub>z</sub>)<sup>2</sup>

Note that although all these equations seem to be quadtratic, the square of P<sub>x</sub> we be scratched because it appears on both sides of the equation. Now use this system of equations and the ones above to find the three variables P<sub>x</sub>, P<sub>y</sub> and P<sub>z</sub>.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong. (Px - Ax)2 = (Px - Bx)2 ==> (Px - Ax) = (Px - Bx) ==> Ax = Bx.                                                    I guess this holds: (Px - Ax)2 + (Py - Ay)2 + (Pz - Az)2= (Px - Bx)2 +(Py - By)2 + (Pz - Bz)2.

Comment: @gmaster what I've written is wrong. I will fix it sorry. Thank you for noting

Comment: and now the equations really are quadratic. :D

Comment: @gmaster still Px^2 will the scratched from the two sides.

Comment: oh sorry.. my bad.. :|